# TikZ (finite) grid with character in each cell

Tags: tikz-pgf

The code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gives me a nice finite 4x4 grid. Now I want to center one character in each cell, how to do this?

By the way, how can I specify the absolute position of my picture and how to stretch it in one direction (i.e. that it becomes a proper rectangle (not a square)).

Comment: Is there a reason why a simple `tabular` would not work?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `\node`s to place text everywhere you want. The are by default centered at the given coordinate which can be changed using the `anchor` and other options.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\node at (-0.75,+0.75) {A};
\node at (-0.25,+0.75) {B};
\node at (+0.25,+0.75) {C};
\node at (+0.75,+0.75) {D};
\node at (-0.75,+0.25) {E};
\node at (-0.25,+0.25) {F};
\node at (+0.25,+0.25) {G};
\node at (+0.75,+0.25) {H};
% ...
\node at (+0.75,-0.75) {Q};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

---

Or using a loop:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);

\newcounter{mycount}
\setcounter{mycount}{`A}
\foreach \y in {+0.75,+0.25,-0.25,-0.75}
  \foreach \x in {-0.75,-0.25,0.25,0.75}
    \node at (\x,\y) {\char\value{mycount}\addtocounter{mycount}{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}%

% Or
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\foreach \x/\y/\m in {+0.75/+0.75/A,-0.75/-0.75/X} % etc
    \node at (\x,\y) {\m};
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image: Loop result]   [image: Loop result 2]

---

You can scale the image in the X or Y direction using `xscale=<number>` and `yscale=<number>`, respectively. Both are scaled with `scale=<number>`.

If you mean with "absolute position" a fixed position on a page you can do this by drawing it relative to the special `current page` node (needs the `remember picture,overlay` option on the picture). If you give more specific information about this I can make an example.

Comment: Ok, thanks! How to control the position, how to stretch it?

Comment: @user4011: I added this. What exactly do you mean with "absolute position"?

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite the code using looping commands?

Comment: @TeX: Yes, it is.

Comment: Fantastic answer!

Comment: How to insert numeric values instead of letters?

Comment: @pceccon: Well, replace the letters with numbers. If you are talking about the looping construct then replace the `\char\value{mycount}` with `\arabic{mycount}`.

Comment: Bit late reply: Is there a way to rotate the grid?

Answer (score 29):

I would place the text using a `matrix of nodes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}]{
A & B & C & D \\
E & F &  & H \\
I & J & K & L \\
M & N & O & P\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: matrix]

To get rectangular nodes, you can adjust `xstep` and `ystep` separately (and `text width` and `minimum height` accordingly):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[xstep=0.75cm,ystep=0.5,color=gray] (0,0) grid (3,2);
\matrix[matrix of nodes,
inner sep=0pt,
anchor=south west,
nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.75cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}
]{
A & B & C & D \\
E & F &  & H \\
I & J & K & L \\
M & N & O & P\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: matrix rectangular]

Comment: This is the better answer imho. Caveat, though: When using it in beamer, take a look at this, too: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208408/tikz-matrix-undefined-control-sequence

Answer (score 11):

Using the `grid` shape from [my answer to “Drawing a tree of grids”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14846/drawing-a-tree-of-grids/14849#14849), you can access the centers of the squares in the grid:

```
% Code assumes that the grid shape has been added (e.g. in the preamble).
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[  draw,
            grid,
            grid lines=3,
            minimum width=2cm,
            minimum height=2cm
         ] (letters) {};
    \node at (letters.center 1 4) {A};
    \node at (letters.center 2 4) {B};
    \node at (letters.center 3 4) {C};
    \node at (letters.center 4 4) {D};
    \node at (letters.center 1 3) {E};
    \node at (letters.center 2 3) {F};
    \node at (letters.center 3 3) {G};
    \node at (letters.center 4 3) {H};
    \node at (letters.center 1 2) {I};
    \node at (letters.center 2 2) {J};
    \node at (letters.center 3 2) {K};
    \node at (letters.center 4 2) {L};
    \node at (letters.center 1 1) {M};
    \node at (letters.center 2 1) {N};
    \node at (letters.center 3 1) {O};
    \node at (letters.center 4 1) {P};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 9):

This looks like a perfect question for codegolfing ;)
Here is a 4x4 grid with letters from A to P in 93 characters command :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \tikz\draw grid(4,4)foreach[count=~]\l in{A,...,P}{({.5+mod(~-1,4},{3.5-div(~-1,4})node{\l}};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tempting :) I need to find some time. I have still the previous in line for posting

Comment: @percusse Haha. I have things to do that I don't want to do, so I have time for codegolfing ;) But I promise to not tempt you again in the near future.

Answer (score 7):

[Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12861/1952) proposes to place nodes within a matrix and draw the grid with another command. Following code proposes to draw node's contents and grid with the `matrix` command. in this case, all equal size nodes are drawn with a gray border and distance between columns and rows is adjusted to supperpose adjacent borders.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={draw=gray, anchor=center, minimum size=.6cm}, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth] (A) {
A & B & C & D \\
E & F &  & H \\
I & J & K & L \\
M & N & O & P\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does not look nice when the contents of each cell have different width. But tunable with minimum width.

Comment: @visoft Yes, to draw a rectangular grid with a `matrix` you need to fix a `minimum width` and `minimum height` large enough to contain the largest contents.