# Boundary not shown when drawing grid lattice with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw some grids using tikz but some of them don't shown the left vertical boundary. Currently I have to decrease the coordinate of the left boundary a little to make it work, say, change 6 to 5.9999.

Why is this happening? Some kind of numerical issues?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[] at (1,-0.5) {Type 1};
\draw[step=0.4cm] (0,0) grid (2,2); 
\node[] at (3.8,-0.5) {Type 2};
\draw[step=0.4cm] (3.2,0) grid (4.4,2); 
\node[] at (6.4,-0.5) {Type 3};
\draw[step=0.4cm] (6,0) grid (6.8,1.2); 
\node[] at (8.6,-0.5) {Type 4};
\draw[step=0.4cm] (8,0) grid (9.2,1.2);
\node[] at (12,-0.5) {Type 5};
\draw[step=0.4cm] (11.2,0) grid (12.8,1.6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a known precision issue, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13834/2552. In your case, you could work around the problem by drawing all the grids starting from the origin and shifting them horizontally, using something like `\draw [xshift=3.2cm, step=0.4cm] (0,0) grid (1.2,2);` for the Type 2 grid.