# Get outermost coordinates/length in a Tikz-picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, scale

From my previous question/answer [Tikz image within a defined box (& the textpos package)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497575/tikz-image-within-a-defined-box-the-textpos-package), @frougon provided a great solution. And now, I'm seeking to have a standard scaling for all of my Tikz-pictures (see the edit/addition).

I want all of my Tikz-pictures to be 3.5cm x 3.5cm, and I can do this by using `scale = 3.5/k`, where `k` is the "coordinate-length" of the Tikz-picture.

I'm wondering if there is a way to get the outermost (or length of) coordinates in a Tikz-picture? For example,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,4)--(10,7);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

would have `k=9`, as the x-axis ranges from 1 to 10 (a difference of 9), while the y=axis ranges from 4 to 7 (a difference of 3).

I would envision some sort of "maximum" function coming into play here. Something like `k = max(<largest x coordinate> - <smallest x coordinate >, <largest y coordinate > - <smallest y coordinate >) = max(10-1,7-4) = max(9,3) = 9`.

For a more detailed example, consider the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(10,5);
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(5,-10);
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(-10,5);
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(-5,-10);
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(10,-5);
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(-5,10);
    \draw (.5,2) node {1};
    \draw (-2.5,2.5) node {2};
    \draw (-2,-.5) node {3};
    \draw (0,-2.5) node {4};
    \draw (2.5,-2.5) node {5};
    \draw (2.5,0) node {6};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In this case, I would want `k = 20`, as the "length" of the x-axis (and y-axis, in fact), is 20 coordinate units.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This computes the dimensions of the bounding box and the corresponding scale factor, which it applies in the next run. (Replaced `max` by `min`, big thanks to frougon!)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ExportBB[1]{\path let 
 \p1=($(current bounding box.north east)-(current bounding box.south west)$),
 \n1={#1/\x1},\n2={#1/\y1}
 in \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\figscale}{min(\n1,\n2)}\xdef\figscale{\figscale}};
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\figscale{\figscale}\relax}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{scale to max size/.style={execute at end picture={\ExportBB{#1}},
/utils/exec=\ifdefined\figscale
\else
\message{Recompile the figure.}
\xdef\figscale{1}
\fi,scale=\figscale}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale to max size=3.5cm]
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(10,5);
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(5,-10);
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(-10,5);
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(-5,-10);
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(10,-5);
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(-5,10);
    \draw (.5,2) node {1};
    \draw (-2.5,2.5) node {2};
    \draw (-2,-.5) node {3};
    \draw (0,-2.5) node {4};
    \draw (2.5,-2.5) node {5};
    \draw (2.5,0) node {6};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, the texts are not transformed. You could transform them, too, but then it might be more straightforward to use `\maxsizebox{3.5cm}{3.5cm}{....}` that comes with `adjustbox`.

This stores the dimensions in `\n1` and `\n2` in the first example and prints the dimensions in a node in the second example.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,4)--(10,7);
    \path let \p1=($(current bounding box.north east)-(current bounding
    box.south west)$),\n1={\x1/1cm},\n2={\y1/1cm}
    in \pgfextra{\typeout{x=\n1 cm,y=\n2 cm}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[store dimensions of current picture in/.style 2 args={
  insert path={let \p1=($(current bounding box.north east)-(current bounding
    box.south west)$),\n1={\x1/1cm},\n2={\y1/1cm}
    in \pgfextra{\edef#1{\n1}\edef#2{\n2}}}}]
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(10,5);
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(5,-10);
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(-10,5);
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(-5,-10);
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(10,-5);
    \draw[thick] (0,0)--(-5,10);
    \draw (.5,2) node {1};
    \draw (-2.5,2.5) node {2};
    \draw (-2,-.5) node {3};
    \draw (0,-2.5) node {4};
    \draw (2.5,-2.5) node {5};
    \draw (2.5,0) node {6};
    \path[store dimensions of current picture in={\myx}{\myy}]
    node[fill=white] at (current bounding box.center) {%
    $x=\pgfmathparse{\myx}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$cm,
    $y=\pgfmathparse{\myy}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to take the maximum of these lengths and scale the `tikzpicture` by `3.5/maximum`. Also, I'm confused how `\n1` and `\n2` are actually stored and how I would scale the picture (something like `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 3.5/max{\n1, \n2}`)

Comment: @ryanj1823 You cannot know at the beginning of the `tikzpicture` how large it will be. However, `adustbox` allows you to do precisely that, it has some maximum functions of that type.

Comment: ...and of course you did my "difficult solution" in almost no time. marmots rocks!

Comment: @Rmano I was prepared: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497592/121799.

Comment: @marmot Interesting! 1) Despite what the OP [wrote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497748/get-outermost-coordinates-length-in-a-tikz-picture#comment1256962_497749), I bet what he really wants is desired/min(\n1,\n2), not max, otherwise the scaled picture will be either larger or taller than the frame, unless it has a 1:1 aspect ratio (which is the case in the example used here!). 2) I implemented this at the box level (requiring only one pass) in my answer to his [original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497590/73317) once I understood that was desired, but I believe he...

Comment: @marmot... didn't connect yet since then, so couldn't say if this actually does what he wants. There is one significant difference between our techniques, though: mine will scale fonts in the `tikzpicture`s whereas yours won't, as you said (he can use yours with my code, then there should be no font scaling and all should still work).

Comment: @frougon Yes, that's a nice answer (+1). However, let me mention that there is a second difference: if you use `scalebox`, `adjustbox` etc., you can no longer access coordinates with `remember picture`. In many situations this won't matter, but in some it does.

Comment: @marmot Thanks for the complements! I added a paragraph about this (not published yet) but  have one question: if the OP prepares a picture that has `remember picture` using your technique, my code will apply 1:1 scaling using `\scalebox` (that is, if you fix yours to use `min` :-). Is such 1:1 scaling going to break the `remember picture` mechanism, or not? If yes, I'll provide an option to disable automatic scaling for the pictures where it is undesirable. (I will try it if you don't know the answer by heart, of course)

Comment: @frougon I *think* 1:1 will work but I am sure that for other values it generically breaks. (This is one the of the most important drawbacks when solving the "do-not-nest-tikzpicture" issue with saveboxes, and which is why there things like `subnode`s by LoopSpace are really cool.)

Comment: @frougon I agree that `min` is better and corrected it, thanks!

Comment: @frougon I think that this is just a numerical inaccuracy because the symbolic coordinates are stored internally in `pt` units, so Ti*k*Z converts back and forth and loses the edges. Try e.g. `\documentclass[tikz, border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document} 
\path let \p1=($(A)-(1,5)$) in \pgfextra{\typeout{\x1,\y1}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}`. We probably need to live with these limitations.

Comment: @marmot Sorry, I removed my comments about this because I found out this was a [known issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13834/missing-tikz-grid-borders) concerning `grid`, so I had the impression I was only polluting this discussion with some problem not really relevant (now that I know it was not due to your code). Unrelated: I've added support for the `noscale` option in [my code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497590/73317). To be more useful for real-word usage, I believe your code should accept a parameter used as prefix or suffix for the control sequence...

Comment: ...  (currently `\figscale`) written to the `.aux` file. Otherwise, only one figure per document can use this mechanism. Also, I don't know why you put `\relax` after the definition in the `.aux` file.

Comment: @frougon Yes, it is true that it only works for one figure in its present form, and I used `\relax` because LaTeX does not understand `\hibernate`. ;-)

Comment: @marmot I thought you had `\let\hibernate\relax` in the marmotTeX format. ;-) More seriously, I've extended your style a little bit (mainly: to allow several pictures per document and a target frame that isn't necessarily a square). You can see the [short description](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497575/tikz-image-within-a-defined-box-the-textpos-package/497590#comment1257398_497590) and the [code in my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497590/73317).

Comment: @marmot The `noscale` option I mentioned [above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497748/get-outermost-coordinates-length-in-a-tikz-picture/497749?noredirect=1#comment1257299_497749) has been renamed to `autoscale=false` (the corresponding argument is now processed with `l3keys`). In case the OP wants `autoscale=false` to be the default (probably in order to use your scaling technique most of the time), it can be done with a one-word change that is described in my [already-linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497590/73317).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me a kind of [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... I am not sure about the exact semantic you want, but for example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\adjustboxset{min width=3.5cm, min height=3.5cm, max width=3.5cm, max height=3.5cm}

\adjustbox{}{\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,6) (2,2) rectangle (3,3);}
\adjustbox{}{\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (6,4) (2,2) rectangle (3,3);}
\adjustbox{}{\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (6,6) (2,2) rectangle (3,3);}
\adjustbox{}{\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1) (.2,.2) rectangle (.3,.3);}
\end{document}
```

will produce: 
[image]

which can or cannot be what you want (notice the effect of scaling on the smaller picture).

Otherwise, the only other way I see is using [@marmot answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497749/38080), and doing a bit of magic to store the scale factor in the `.aux` file to be used at the second pass. (Too complex now to think about it, no time...)