# Optional argument in a tikz environment

Tags: environments, xparse, optional-arguments, arguments

I use the following `resizedtikzpicture` environment in order to rescale my tikzpictures. Would it be possible to add an optional argument, taking into account the tikz option? For example the color or baseline.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newenvironment{resizedtikzpicture}[1]{%
  \def\mywidth{#1}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  }{%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \resizebox{\mywidth}{!}{\usebox\mybox}%
}

%\newsavebox\mybox
%\newenvironment{wrongresizedtikzpicture}[2][\unskip]{%
%  \def\mywidth{#1}%
%  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
%  \begin{tikzpicture}[ #2]
%  }{%
%  \end{tikzpicture}%
%  \end{lrbox}%
%  \resizebox{\mywidth}{!}{\usebox\mybox}%
%}


\begin{document}
ABCDE

\begin{resizedtikzpicture}{\columnwidth}
\draw [thick,->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
\draw [thick,->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
\draw [very thick, domain=-5:5,samples=200] plot(\x,{\x+0.2});

\draw [very thick, domain=-5:0,samples=200] plot(\x,{\x});
\draw [very thick, domain=0:5,samples=200] plot(\x,{0*\x});

\draw [very thick, domain=-5:0,samples=200] plot(\x,{0*\x});
\draw [very thick, domain=0:5,samples=200] plot(\x,{\x});

\draw (-6,-4.5) node{{\(x \mapsto x\)}};
\end{resizedtikzpicture}

% Goal :
%\begin{resizedtikzpicture}{\columnwidth}[baseline=0]
%\draw [thick,->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
%\draw [thick,->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
%\draw [very thick, domain=-5:5,samples=200] plot(\x,{\x+0.2});
%
%\draw [very thick, domain=-5:0,samples=200] plot(\x,{\x});
%\draw [very thick, domain=0:5,samples=200] plot(\x,{0*\x});
%
%\draw [very thick, domain=-5:0,samples=200] plot(\x,{0*\x});
%\draw [very thick, domain=0:5,samples=200] plot(\x,{\x});
%
%\draw (-6,-4.5) node{{\(x \mapsto x\)}};
%\end{resizedtikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to learn how to prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/73317) and maybe to read the error message when you encounter an error (“it doesn't work” is not an error message; it is not actionable). The following does work, but the method used [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/532190/73317) is better, as it wouldn't scale fonts.

Note: I used `[{#2}]` instead of `[#2]` because only the former works fine if `#2` contains square brackets, which is bound to happen sooner or later.

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newenvironment{resizedtikzpicture}[2]{%
  \def\mywidth{#1}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[{#2}]
  }{%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \resizebox{\mywidth}{!}{\usebox\mybox}%
}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[{\lipsum[1]}]

\noindent
\makebox[0pt][l]{abcd.}%
\begin{resizedtikzpicture}{\columnwidth}{baseline=0}
  \draw [thick,->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
  \draw [thick,->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
  \draw [very thick, domain=-5:5,samples=200] plot(\x,{\x+0.2});

  \draw [very thick, domain=-5:0,samples=200] plot(\x,{\x});
  \draw [very thick, domain=0:5,samples=200] plot(\x,{0*\x});

  \draw [very thick, domain=-5:0,samples=200] plot(\x,{0*\x});
  \draw [very thick, domain=0:5,samples=200] plot(\x,{\x});

  \draw (-6,-4.5) node{{\(x \mapsto x\)}};
\end{resizedtikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Making the second argument optional

If you want to make the second argument optional, this is not straightforward with `\newenvironment`, but `xparse` makes it easy:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox\mybox
\NewDocumentEnvironment{resizedtikzpicture}{mO{}}{%
  \def\mywidth{#1}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[{#2}]
  }{%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \resizebox{\mywidth}{!}{\usebox\mybox}%
}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[{\lipsum[1]}]

\noindent
\makebox[0pt][l]{abcd.}%
\begin{resizedtikzpicture}{\columnwidth}[baseline=0]
  \draw [thick,->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
  \draw [thick,->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
  \draw [very thick, domain=-5:5,samples=200] plot(\x,{\x+0.2});

  \draw [very thick, domain=-5:0,samples=200] plot(\x,{\x});
  \draw [very thick, domain=0:5,samples=200] plot(\x,{0*\x});

  \draw [very thick, domain=-5:0,samples=200] plot(\x,{0*\x});
  \draw [very thick, domain=0:5,samples=200] plot(\x,{\x});

  \draw (-6,-4.5) node{{\(x \mapsto x\)}};
\end{resizedtikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(same output as above).

## Optional argument without `xparse`

There is no reason to avoid `xparse` which is great, but just for the record, you could have your optional argument with `\newenvironment` if you accept to have this argument in first position:

```latex
\newenvironment{resizedtikzpicture}[2][]{%
  \def\mywidth{#2}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[{#1}]
  }{%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \resizebox{\mywidth}{!}{\usebox\mybox}%
}

...

\begin{resizedtikzpicture}[baseline=0]{\columnwidth}
```

Comment: Thank's, but with this solution the second argument is not optional (that's my problem).

Comment: Ah, I had not understood that from your question, since you wrote “Goal : `\begin{resizedtikzpicture}{\columnwidth}{baseline=0}`”, which is a syntax for a mandatory argument. I have added another example where the second argument is optional (thus, you were right tagging the question with `xparse` and I'll readd it).