# tikz grid missing leftmost line

Tags: tikz-pgf

For the TikZ grid command, I am wondering why the leftmost line is missing from the second grid that I am drawing below when I specify a step and do not start at (0,0).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue] (0,0) grid[step=5mm] (3,3);
  \draw[red] (4,0) grid[step=5mm] (7,3);
  \draw[green!50!black, xshift=8cm]  grid[step=5mm] (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\smallskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue] (0,0) grid (3,3);
  \draw[red] (4,0) grid (7,3);
  \draw[green!50!black, xshift=8cm]  grid (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13835/197451

Comment: would you like to accept the answer if it has met your requirement

Comment: Thanks to @jsbibra for  point to the answer - it's a known "feature" of PGF. How do I mark this as a duplicate of that?

Comment: done marked as duplicate

Comment: would you like to accept the answer if it has met your requirement – js bibra 2 days ago

Answer (score 0):

[image]

edit as below

```
  \draw[red] (4-0.001,0-0.001) grid[step=5mm] (7,3);
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue] (0,0) grid[step=5mm] (3,3);
  \draw[red] (4-0.001,0-0.001) grid[step=5mm] (7,3);
  \draw[green!50!black, xshift=8cm]  grid[step=5mm] (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\smallskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue] (0,0) grid (3,3);
  \draw[red] (4,0) grid (7,3);
  \draw[green!50!black, xshift=8cm]  grid (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```