# Creating Tic-Tac-Toe boards with LaTeX/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, trees

I am trying to create a diagram of tic-tac-toe boards similar to the one attached below.

[image: tic-tac-toe boards]

I cannot seem to find any documentation or examples on how to create these boards in LaTeX or TikZ. Does anyone know of a solution for this sort of diagram?

Comment: You can make trees with TikZ, `forest` or many other packages. You can do these boards inside TikZ with matrices, `tabular`s or manually. Anything tried already?

Comment: I have made trees in TikZ in the past, and I am currently reading up on tables in TikZ, but I am still unsure how to combine the two. That is, how do I replace the nodes of the tree with the tables themselves? Thank you for your response.

Comment: When you write `\node {...}` between the brackets you can put pretty much anything, even tables and nested `tikzpicture` environment (useful here if you want really fine control on how the tables are typeset).

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that! I will give this a try then. Thanks!

Comment: [Drawing a tree of grids](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14846/7279)

Comment: Where did you get the image from?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is far from perfect but does the job, though, I would use other connections.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,calc}
\forestset{
  make tab/.style args={#1:#2:#3/#4:#5:#6/#7:#8:#9}{%
    content={%
      \tabcolsep=.6\tabcolsep
      \begin{tabular}{p{\widthof{x}}|p{\widthof{x}}|p{\widthof{x}}}
        #1 & #2 & #3\\\hline#4&#5&#6\\\hline#7&#8&#9
      \end{tabular}}},
  label position r/.initial=right,
  label position b/.initial=below
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  TTT/.style args={#1:#2}{
    make tab/.expanded=\forestove{content},
    label={\pgfkeysvalueof{/forest/label position #1}:$#2$}
  },
  TTT*/.style={
    make tab=::/::/::,
    content/.expand once=%
    \expandafter\vphantom\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0\forestov{content}},
    draw=none,
    append after command={(\tikzlastnode.north) edge (\tikzlastnode.south)},
    for descendants={before computing xy={l*=1.2}},
  },
  th/.style=thick,
  for tree={node options=draw, inner sep=+0pt, parent anchor=south, child anchor=north}
%
[::/::/::, TTT=r:1
 [x::/::/::, TTT=r:-1
   [x:o:/::/::, TTT=b: 1, th]
   [x::/:o:/::, TTT=b:-1]
   [x::o/::/::, TTT=b: 0, th]
   [x::/::/::o, TTT=b: 0, th]
   [x::/::o/::, TTT=b: 1, th]
]
 [::/:x:/::, TTT=r:1,
   [,TTT* % this is just cheating :(
    [o::/:x:/::, TTT=b:1]
    [:o:/:x:/::, TTT=b:2]
   ]
 ]
 [:x:/::/::, TTT=r:-2
   [:x:o/::/::, TTT=b:-1, th]
   [:x:/:o:/::, TTT=b:-2]
   [:x:/::/:o:, TTT=b: 0, th]
   [:x:/::/o::, TTT=b:-1, th]
   [:x:/o::/::, TTT=b: 0, th]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]