# How can I draw a diagram for matrix multiplication with LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, matrices

I'm trying to make a PDF manual for matrix multiplication with LaTeX. I'd like to generate a graphic similar to this one (from [Wikipedia/Matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)):

[image: Matrix multiplication]

I guess this will be quite a bit of work, but is there another way than using the eepic package? I have read into some examples and the manual, and it seems very complex to generate a graphic like this with that package.

If there is no other way, I'll have to use eepic, but I hope someone here could point me to a package or another way.

Comment: This reminds my on [TikZ (finite) grid with character in each cell](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12856/2975), but using matrices as Stefan suggested might be better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I recommend to use [TikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and its matrix library, specifically the `matrix of math nodes feature`. TikZ offers a great and comprehensive [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

Have a look at this example and its source code, written by Alain Matthes, in the TikZ example gallery: [Matrix multiplication](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/matrix-multiplication/). It deals exactly with your subject.

[image: matrix example]

Comment: Wow. This really is /exactly/ what I'm looking for. I'll translate the few words into German and I'm done. Way prettier than I thought ever possible. Thanks a ton :)