# Printing inside Grid using Two Loops

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

I am trying to rearrange the value inside grid. For example, the below code

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone} 

\begin{document}

\tikz\draw grid(4,4)foreach[count=~]\l in{1,...,16}  
{({.5+mod(~-1,4},{3.5-div(~-1,4})node{\l}}; 

\end{document}
```

gives a 4*4 grid where each box has a number from 1 to 16.
like-

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

How can I perform the same thing using two *for loop* such that the grid becomes-

```
1  2  2   1
3  4  4   3
3  4  4   3
1  2  2   1
```

For 8 rows and 8 column, each quadrant should start with 1 and end with 16.

```
    1  2  3  4     4  3  2  1  
    5  6  7  8     8  7  6  5  
    9  10 11 12    12 11 10 9
    13 14 15 16    16 15 14 13

    13 14 15 16    16 15 14 13  
    9  10 11 12    12 11 10 9
    5  6  7   8    8  7  6  5
    1  2  3   4    4  3  2  1
```

Also , How can I print inside grid such as-

```
a=1  a=2  a=2   a=1
a=3  a=4  a=4   a=3
a=3  a=4  a=4   a=3
a=1  a=2  a=2   a=1
```

I am trying to construct the general code that is valid for x rows and y columns instead of 4 rows and 4 columns.

I found the above code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12856/tikz-finite-grid-with-character-in-each-cell).

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Rather than posting a code snippet, it is better to post a compilable minimal document.  Also, please show us what you have tried to get a double loop.

Comment: @AndrewSwann if u want the generic code for the value rearrangement, I can give it to you. I have searched and am still searching on SE regarding post,  but found no help so far!

Comment: The easy solution is to create a tikz array `\def\myarray{{1,2,2,1,3,4,4,3,3,4,4,3,1,2,2,1}}`.  See page 927 of PGF manual.

Comment: If you have the algorithm that generates those numbers (based on i and j indices, I suppose?), please do add that to the question.

Comment: Andrew means that you should post a complete and compileable code example that people can run without additional changes.

Comment: You said above that you could provide "generic code" for this grids, why not add that to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you get a double loop, you add a second `foreach` inside the expression `{...}` that the first `foreach` loops over.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikz\draw grid(4,4) foreach \x  in {1,...,4}
  { foreach[evaluate={\z = int((\x*(5-\x)/2+\y*(5-\y))-5)}] \y in {1,...,4}
  {({.5+(\x-1)},{4.5-\y}) node{$a = \z$}}};

\end{document}
```

To change the values printed, just adjust the formula for `\z` in the `evaluate` statement.  Note that `int` is used here, so that a decimal answer `1.0` etc. is not display.

Here is a version for your new pattern specification with variables `\n` and `\m` (even numbers) giving the total number of columns and rows, and a variable `\s` storing a dimension to scale the box size so the contents fit:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\n{6}
\def\m{8}
\def\s{1.5cm}
\tikz\draw grid[step=\s](\n*\s,\m*\s) foreach[evaluate] \x  in {1,...,\n}
  { foreach[evaluate={\z = int(min(\x,\n+1-\x)+\n*min(\y-1,\m-\y)/2)}] \y in {1,...,\m}
  {({\s*(.5+(\x-1))},{\s*(\m+.5-\y)}) node{$a=\z$}}};

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365705/using-condition-if-else-inside-loop-for-in-tikz

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone} 
\begin{document}
\tikz\draw grid(4,4)foreach
    [evaluate={\x=.5+mod(\l-1,4);\y=3.5-div(\l-1,4);\z=int(5-(\x-2)^2/2-(\y-2)^2)}]
    \l in{1,...,16}{(\x,\y)node{$a=\z$}};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it  in the general form ? can I use it for 10 rows and  25 columns? of-course I have change value for $l$ , but what else need to be changed? would u plz provide the general form?

Comment: @MikeSQ If you don't tell what's the rule for filling in the array, nobody can help to extend it.

Comment: the rule is same , so what u 've done for 4 rows and 4 columns, will be done for 10 rows and 25 or 26 columns. To be precise, u generalize the same procedure for  x rows and y columns instead of  4 rows and 4 columns.

Comment: @MikeSQ You give a single sample and say "generalize from it". Even in the intelligence tests they give you more than one example, for the simple reason that otherwise the task is highly ambiguous. In your application, will a longer first line read `1 2 3 4 ... 4 3 2 1` or `1 2 2 ... 2 1`? How are the lines further down constructed? The only rule that seems to be apparent is that there  is a left-right and top-bottom symmetry.

Comment: @gernot  each quadrant should be symmetric, plz see the post, I have added an example of  8 rows and 8 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?  (Now that I've corrected the symmetry...)

[image]

I produced this with the following [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) code, wrapped up in [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en).  Compile with `lualatex`.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    numeric u, v, N; N = 2; 
    u = 14mm; v = 9mm;
    for i=0 upto 3:
        for j=0 upto N-1:
            for k=0 upto N-1:
                label("$a=" & decimal (N**2-(k+N*j)) & "$", 
                      (k+2/3,j+2/3) xscaled u yscaled v
                      if (i mod 3) > 0: reflectedabout(up,down) fi
                      if i > 1: reflectedabout(left,right) fi
                );
            endfor
        endfor
    endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

If you set `N=4` in the above you get:

[image]

and so on...

[image]

The values are generated by the `label` in the middle of the three loops.  Specifically `decimal (N**2-(k+N*j))` generates a string with the value of `N^2-(k+N*j)` -- if you want different numbers you can adjust this formula.  So to get numbers starting at `a=1` in the middle, you could change the formula to `decimal (1+k+N*j)`.

If you wanted the numbers is some other order, then you could (for example) swap the values of `j` and `k` in the coordinates to get a column-first sequence, or subtract them from `N` to get the numbers in reverse order.

Comment: +1 , but would u plz address the problem when we want start with a=1 instead of a=16 ?

Comment: Where is the "start" ?  in the middle or at the outer corner?

Comment: ur top-left,bottom-left, top-right,bottom-right corner started with a=16 for N=4, what if I want to start top-left,bottom-left, top-right,bottom-right corner with a=1 for N=4?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: File `luatex85.sty' not found.  ...errrrr!!  latex is really out of reach for beginner!!!!           Now I have to know which file is required and where to keep them!!!                                                            By the way, where is the grid? spacing between each quadrant is not required but grid is.