# Using Condition (If/Else) Inside Loop (For) In Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, grids

In my [previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/363912/130778), I have asked how to use two loops to construct a grid with values inside it. A wonderful [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/363995/130778)  was given by *Andrew Swann* .

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\n{6}
\def\m{8}
\def\s{1.5cm}
\tikz\draw grid[step=\s](\n*\s,\m*\s) foreach[evaluate] \x  in {1,...,\n}
  { foreach[evaluate={\z = int(min(\x,\n+1-\x)+\n*min(\y-1,\m-\y)/2)}] \y in {1,...,\m}
  {({\s*(.5+(\x-1))},{\s*(\m+.5-\y)}) node{$a=\z$}}};

\end{document}
```

he has provided a formula `\z` which can be modified for different arrangement of values.

For example, I did-

> [evaluate= {\z = int(\x+\n*min(\y-1,\m+\y))}]

which gives-

> 1 2 3 4
>
> 5 6  7 8
>
> 9 10 11 12

for 3*4 grid. But if I want -

> 1 2 2 1
>
> 3 4 4 3
>
> 5 6 6 5
>
> 7 8 8 7

and ,

> 1 2  3  4
>
> 5 6  7  8
>
> 0 9  10 0
>
> 0 11 12 0
>
> 0 13 14 0

I could not do it! I am really having hard time to use loop and if else condition. Probably , I am too much used to C++ and similar things where I can easily do a=a+1 or write if condition. I can think of an way to print above value-arrangements, using ***Condition*** (if/else), but I don't know where to put it (I have tried, but all were wrong).

So,my question is, how to put ***Condition*** (if/else) before `\z` so that I can print output as I have shown above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could easily use ifthenelse in the tikz node:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\def\n{4}
\def\m{4}
\def\s{1.5cm}
\tikz\draw grid[step=\s](\n*\s,\m*\s) 
  foreach[evaluate] \x  in {1,...,\n} { 
    foreach[evaluate={
      \zt = int(\x+\n*min(\y-1,\m+\y));
      \zb = int(\x+(\n-2)*min(\y-1,\m+\y)+3)
    }] \y in {1,...,\m} {
      ({\s*(.5+(\x-1))},{\s*(\m+.5-\y)}) node{$a=\ifthenelse{\y>2}{\ifthenelse{\x=1 \OR \x>3}{0}{\zb}}{\zt}$}
    }
  };

\end{document}
```

This should create the third grid you wanted.

Also see the answer to the following question for more examples with ifthenelse and loops:
[If-then-else inside TikZ graph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187482/if-then-else-inside-tikz-graph)

Answer (score 7):

You can use in TikZ the "conditional assignment" sentence, which you probably know from C language. The syntax is `result = cond?v0:v1`. If the condition `cond` is true, `v0` will be assigned to `result`, otherwise `v1` is assigned.

This expression can be used as part of the `evaluate` key in your code. Also, the expression can be nested inside another conditional assignment, as for example: `result = cond1?(cond2?v0:v1):v2`

So, in your case (code adapted from val's answer):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\n{4}
\def\m{4}
\def\s{1.5cm}
\noindent\tikz\draw grid[step=\s](\n*\s,\m*\s) 
  foreach[evaluate] \x  in {1,...,\n} { 
    foreach[evaluate={
      \zt = int(\x+\n*min(\y-1,\m+\y));
      \zb = int(\x+(\n-2)*min(\y-1,\m+\y)+3);
      \zr = \y>2?((\x==1)||(\x>3)?0:\zb):\zt     % <-------- see here
    }] \y in {1,...,\m} {
      ({\s*(.5+(\x-1))},{\s*(\m+.5-\y)}) node{\zr}
    }
  };

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

One could use the comparison/logical maths functions of [`pgf`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) (89.3.5 Comparison and logical functions in the 3.0.1a manual) such as `equal(x,y)` which returns `0` if `x` and `y` are not equal and otherwise returns `1`, and `greater(x,y)` which returns `1` if `x>y` and otherwise `0` and incorporate these into your `evaluate` instruction along with the `min` and `max` functions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\def\n{4}
\def\m{6}
\def\blnk{1}
\def\mx{8}
\def\s{1.5cm}
\tikz\draw grid[step=\s](\n*\s,\m*\s) foreach \x  in {1,...,\n}
  { foreach[evaluate={\z = int(divide(\n,2)*(\y-1)+min(\x,\n+1-\x))}] \y in {1,...,\m}
  {({\s*(.5+(\x-1))},{\s*(\m+.5-\y)}) node{$a=\z$}}};
\tikz\draw grid[step=\s](\n*\s,\m*\s) foreach \x  in {1,...,\n}
  { foreach[evaluate={\z = int(notless(\n*(\y-1),\mx)*greater(min(\x-\blnk,\n+1-\x-\blnk),0)*((\n-2*\blnk)*(\y-ceil(divide(\mx,\n))-1)  +\x-\blnk+\n*ceil(divide(\mx,\n)))+less(\n*(\y-1),\mx)*(\n*(\y-1)+\x))}] \y in {1,...,\m}
  {({\s*(.5+(\x-1))},{\s*(\m+.5-\y)}) node{$a=\z$}}};
\end{document}
```

[image]

For your first example, the function `int(divide(\n,2)*(\y-1)+min(\x,\n+1-\x))` seems to meet with your first example, not really requiring any condition just the `min` function with an appropriate `+\x` and `-\x` term.

The piece-wise nature is introduced through use of `notless` and `greater` functions acting as multipliers to the actual number of interest, which have the same sort of effect as the conditionals you were after.

One can imagine a more general case which describes your second case, which prints all numbers up until some the row in which `\mx` occurs, after which it places a number `\blnk` of zeros as padding on either side while still increasing continuously for which the `int(notless(\n*(\y-1),\mx)*greater(min(\x-\blnk,\n+1-\x-\blnk),0)*((\n-2*\blnk)*(\y-ceil(divide(\mx,\n))-1)+\x-\blnk+\n*ceil(divide(\mx,\n)))+less(\n*(\y-1),\mx)*(\n*(\y-1)+\x))` function seems to do the job, `ceil` rounds up to the nearest integer.

For a more minimal case of only representing the function you want `int(notless(\y,3)*greater(min(\x-1,\n-\x),0)*((\n-2)*(\y-3)+\x+7)+less(\y,3)*(4*(\y-1)+\x))` works, again using `notless and`less`to separate into two cases, and the`min`function inside the`greater` function to identify which columns should have a zero.