# tikz grid without top edge

Tags: tikz-pgf

In this code from [TikZ (finite) grid with character in each cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12856/tikz-finite-grid-with-character-in-each-cell)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}]{
A & B & C & D \\
E & F &  & H \\
I & J & K & L \\
M & N & O & P\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to delete the top and left edges of the grid.

I have found solutions using `node`s but much prefer this one with a `matrix`.

Comment: Off topic: You have a very nice reputation number :)

Comment: @JouleV Indeed, It won't survive any votes on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `\foreach`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\foreach \i in {-0.5,0,0.5,1} {
    \draw[gray] (-1,-\i)--(1,-\i);
    \draw[gray] (\i,-1)--(\i,1);
}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}]{
A & B & C & D \\
E & F &  & H \\
I & J & K & L \\
M & N & O & P\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Honestly I don't think nodes or matrices have any thing to do here.

---

This approach is based on [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot)['s creative way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481347/tikz-grid-without-top-edge/481350?noredirect=1#comment1216577_481350), which is nicer and more tricky:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] ({-1cm+0.2pt},-1) grid (1cm,{1cm-0.2pt});
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}]{
A & B & C & D \\
E & F &  & H \\
I & J & K & L \\
M & N & O & P\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. There is a "matrix" in the code. Other answers to my original question used nodes.

Comment: @EthanBolker No problem. You are welcome ;)

Comment: Maybe mention also `\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (-0.99,-1) grid (1,0.99);` which is shorter and gives (for all practical purposes) the same output.

Comment: @marmot Ohh your way is wonderfully creative :)) I did not even think of that. However they are not mathematically correct.

Comment: @JouleV What do you mean by "not mathematically correct"? It is as correct as a truncated grid can be.

Comment: @marmot As I know the default value of `line width` is 0.4pt, so to make it mathematically correct I think we should use `\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] ({-1cm+0.2pt},-1) grid (1cm,{1cm-0.2pt});` :)

Comment: @JouleV And what about the `line cap`? BTW, this is why I wrote "or all practical purposes".

Comment: @marmot That's why I wrote "mathematically" :)

Comment: I see. "mathematically" = "doesn't matter" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution. It draws the grid with a `matrix` of `drawn` nodes. After that, left and top border are *deleted* with a white supperposed line.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={draw=gray, anchor=center, minimum size=.6cm}, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth] (A) {
A & B & C & D \\
E & F &  & H \\
I & J & K & L \\
M & N & O & P\\};
\draw[white] ([xshift=.5\pgflinewidth]A-4-1.south west)|-([yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]A-1-4.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]